# Alternatives to Webpack styelint-webpack-plugin? Looking for a maintained project

Tags: css, webpack, sass, webpack-4, stylelint

I'm looking to install Webpack4 for a project.

Part of what I want it to do is lint css.

Just about every resource I find points to "stylelint-webpack-plugin" (https://github.com/JaKXz/stylelint-webpack-plugin).

That project's not been getting updated for a long time.

From what I can tell the webpack team bullied the dev responsibile for lots of the work on stylelint-webpack-plugin right out of the community.

So now the project's got nobody doing the work and it's  "looking for a maintainer".  After that whole mess, doesn't look like anyone's signing up.

From my perspective -- Oh Well!  Next !?

Is there a different alternative to stylelint-webpack-plugin for lint-ing styles in a webpack setup?

Answer (score 0):

The `stylelint-webpack-plugin` now belongs to the official `webpack-contrib` GitHub organisation. The plugin's dependencies are up-to-date and it supports the latest version of stylelint (version 9).

I believe it is the still the most appropriate plugin for using stylelint within Webpack.

Comment: No, it doesn't support stylelint version9.  That's the point of my post -- it hasn't been updated. https://github.com/webpack-contrib/stylelint-webpack-plugin/issues/149